# Copy images from SFTP to S3 using Lambda (node)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I am using 'ssh2-sftp-client' to do this job. So basically it works fine if I copy the file to /tmp/ folder of Lambda first and then upload it to s3. I want to point the read stream to s3 without saving in the lambda /tmp/ folder.

So basically:

```
let sftp = new Client();
sftp.connect({
    host: Config.host,
    port: Config.port,
    username: Config.user,
    password: Config.password
}).then(() => {
    return sftp.list('/photos');
}).then((files) => {
    return get(files)
}).then((streams) => {
     return streamToString(streams)
}).then((dataArray) => {
    return uploadToS3.putBatch(Config,dataArray)
}).then(() => {
    return cleanSFTP();
}).then(() => {
    context.done();
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Catch Error: ', err);
    context.fail();
});
```

Get readstream from sftp:

```
  function get(files) {
        return Promise.all(files.slice(0, 2).map((file) => {
            fileList.push(file.name);
            return sftp.get(BASIC_URL + '/' + file.name);
        }));
    }
```

Stream to string:

```
 var streamToArray = require('stream-to-array')
module.exports = function (fileStreams) {
  return Promise.all(fileStreams.map((file) => {
    return fileToArray(file)
  }))
}


function fileToArray(fileStream) {
  return streamToArray(fileStream)
    .then((fileArray) => {
      return {data: fileArray, key: fileStream.path}
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err
    })
}
```

Uploading to s3:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));

function putBatch(config, files) {

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  // Make all the putObject calls immediately
  // Will return rejected promise if any requests fail
  return Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
    if (typeof file.key && file.data !== undefined) {
      var params = {
        Bucket: config.bucket,
        Key: "preix/" + file.key,
        Body: file.data
      };
      return s3.putObject(params).promise()
    }
  }));
};
```

Using this the images get copied to s3 but they have different sizes from what is in sftp and images can not be previewed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the s3-sftp-bridge, it works seamlessly.

https://github.com/gilt/s3-sftp-bridge

Just needs the s3 location and sftp location with credentials, it is automatically get synced.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have seen that. Thanks

Comment: Do you know at what rate the files are being copied? I feel like it is slow? are you happy with the speed? would it work with more images...

Comment: Yes. Happy with the speed and work seamlessly within the cloud.

Comment: that is repo has not been updated in a long time or receives much input from traffic, so fair warning to others trying this out